# Hangouts in systray on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, system-tray

there's a way to have the hangouts icon in the systray?

i'm trying to use the dconf editor, but i don't known the specific exeption that i have to put in the whitelist string for the hangouts icon. Do you know it?

ps: i don't wont to use the ['all'] option because i want to see only the hangouts icon.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put 'exe' into the whitelist, that's the name of the window.

I found it out by enabling debug logs in unity (UNITY_LOG_SEVERITY="=DEBUG;nux=DEBUG" unity --replace &) and watching for the string 'TrayChild' accepted/rejected as I clicked on the Hangouts icon on the Chrome toolbar.

Comment: It does not work for me... any additional consideration with Chrome 34?

Answer (score -3):

I don't have hangouts, but it seems these are all the names of the processes (which you can get e.g. from the system-monitor). Maybe just try this ?